# generate_n with constructor which takes two arguments

Tags: c++, constructor

Hi
I'm trying to do the following:

```
struct A {
A(int i, int j){}
}

int startValue = 10;
vector<A> v;
generate_n(back_inserter(v), 10, ???;
```

How can I "deliver" the two arguments startValue and the functor rand?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since a generator is a function object, you can instantiate the generator and provide arguments to its constructor:

```
class MyGenerator
{
private:
   int startValue;
public:
   MyGenerator(int startValue): startValue(startValue) {}

   // generate an instance of A
   A operator()() 
   {
       return A(startValue, rand()); // or whatever you were planning to do here...                
   }
};

...
//down in your code (added Fred's sugestion)
generate_n(back_inserter(v), 10, MyGenerator(startValue));
```

Then each time you generate you can use startValue and rand to calculate the next parameters to use to construct your A object.

Comment: generate_n(back_inserter(v), 10, MyGenerator(startValue));